# How can I add the glass stamp to the bottle?

Tags: modeling, mesh, glass

I'm trying to add this to my model but I can't figure out how to.

[image: This is what I'm trying to model]

[image: This is my current mesh]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import your image as a plane, Shrinkwrap it to the bottle and set Wrap Method to Project.

[image: Logo]

To get the circle around your logo you could just add a circle, extrude it a bit outwards to give it some width and similarly Shrinkwrap it to your bottle. To Shrinkwrap the circle rotate it towards the bottle. Then Solidify it the amount that looks good.

[image: extrude circle]

[image: Project circle]

[image: circle around the logo]

Next give your bottle a Union Boolean from your circle and Bevel it.

[image: Bevel]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm having trouble shrinkwraping the circle to the bottle https://i.imgur.com/sRvYlVz.png

Comment: I added an image of how the circle should look like.

Comment: Thank for all the help! it worked perfectly

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help.